# How to SetValue Of GetProperty in base class in csharp C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, reflection

i have the following code:

```
public IEnumerable<T> PageData<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, int pageNumber, int pageSize, bool trace)
    {
        var skip = 0;
        if (pageNumber > 0)
        {
            skip = pageNumber - 1;
        }

        List<T> data;
        using (IDbConnection db = _dbFactory.OpenDbConnection())
        {
            var totalResults = db.Select<T>(predicate);
            data = totalResults.Skip(pageSize * skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();

            if (data.Any())
            {
                var firstRecord = data.FirstOrDefault();
                if (firstRecord != null)
                {
                    data.FirstOrDefault().GetType().GetProperty("TotalCount").SetValue(this, totalResults.Count(), null);
                    data.FirstOrDefault().GetType().GetProperty("TotalPages").SetValue(this, totalResults.Count() / pageSize, null);
                    data.FirstOrDefault().GetType().GetProperty("PageNow").SetValue(this, pageNumber, null);
                }
            }

            if (trace) { TraceOut(db.GetLastSql()); }
        }
        return data;
    }
```

However my properties are within inherited into T as a base class.   How would I set the value when the getProperty is within base.property.

When i try, i get the following error:

Object does not match target type

this is on line:

```
data.FirstOrDefault().GetType().GetProperty("TotalCount").SetValue(this, totalResults.Count(), null);
```

The properties do exist, there fine, just inside base.

thanks

Comment: Hold up, You pass in `this` for `SetValue` are you trying to set the property of the calling class or are you trying to set the property of `firstRecord`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you need no reflection. You can do it in a type-safe manner like

```
public IEnumerable<T> PageData<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, 
     int pageNumber, int pageSize, bool trace) where T: BaseClass
```

where `BaseClass` is your base class contains `TotalCount`, etc.

Comment: Hi thanks,  but my T is not a base class,  it just inherits badeclass

Comment: T may be equal to products for example,  but just inherits base class for the repeated values,  would this still work,  have always wondered how u use this method in real life,  thanks

Comment: Yes it should work. Your base class' properties will be visible in generic method when you define constraint like this, and you can use `data.TotalCount` directly without using reflection. You can see other answers for more details.

Answer (score 1):

> However my properties are within inherited into T as a base class.

All you need to do is constain `T` to the base class. You will then be able to use the setters directly.

```
public IEnumerable<T> PageData<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, 
                                  int pageNumber, 
                                  int pageSize, 
                                  bool trace) 
                                  where T: BaseClassName
{
    var skip = 0;
    if (pageNumber > 0)
    {
        skip = pageNumber - 1;
    }

    List<T> data;
    using (IDbConnection db = _dbFactory.OpenDbConnection())
    {
        var totalResults = db.Select<T>(predicate);
        data = totalResults.Skip(pageSize * skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();

        if (data.Any())
        {
            var firstRecord = data.FirstOrDefault();
            if (firstRecord != null)
            {
                int count = totalResults.Count();
                firstRecord.TotalCount = count
                firstRecord.TotalPages = count / pageSize;
                firstRecord.PageNow = pageNumber;
            }
        }

        if (trace) { TraceOut(db.GetLastSql()); }
    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: thanks, well explained, but the marked answer was the first post :-)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you don't need reflection at all.

You seem to know for sure that your T has the required properties because it derives from a base class that has them. So just add a generic constraint to your method.

```
public IEnumerable<T> PageData<T>(
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, int pageNumber, int pageSize, bool trace)
    where T: Baseclass
{
    var skip = 0;
    if (pageNumber > 0)
    {
        skip = pageNumber - 1;
    }

    List<T> data;
    using (IDbConnection db = _dbFactory.OpenDbConnection())
    {
        var totalResults = db.Select<T>(predicate);
        data = totalResults.Skip(pageSize * skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();

        if (data.Any())
        {
            var firstRecord = data.FirstOrDefault();
            if (firstRecord != null)
            {
                firstRecord.TotalCount = totalResults.Count();
                firstRecord.TotalPages = 
                    (totalResults.Count() + pageSize - 1) / pageSize;
                firstRecord.PageNow = pageNumber;
            }
        }

        if (trace) { TraceOut(db.GetLastSql()); }
    }
    return data;
}
```

By the way, your calculation of TotalPages is wrong. See above for a better calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make sure the type you use to get the property is the same type as the object you pass as the first parameter of `SetValue`:

```
var firstRecord = data.FirstOrDefault();
if (firstRecord != null)
{
    firstRecord.GetType().GetProperty("TotalCount").SetValue(firstRecord, totalResults.Count(), null);
    ...
}
```

Or this:

```
var firstRecord = data.FirstOrDefault();
if (firstRecord != null)
{
    typeof(T).GetProperty("TotalCount").SetValue(firstRecord, totalResults.Count(), null);
    ...
}
```